# Error while parsing Tinymce Editor string

Tags: c#, itext

I am parsing the HTML with the help of following code. The html comes from tinymce editor. I have just shortened my code. There can be any number of images in the `EmailBody string` as it is selected by the user in tinymce editor.

All works good except when there is `<img src="">` tag in the Email Body.

I get the error on this line `htmlWorker.Parse(sr);`

```
string EmailBody = @"<p><img src=""http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/smile/smile-07.jpg""></p>";
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    //Create an iTextSharp Document which is an abstraction of a PDF but **NOT** a PDF
    using (var doc = new Document())
    {
        //Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our stream
        using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))
        {
            //Open the document for writing
            doc.Open();
            using (var htmlWorker = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker(doc))
            {
                //HTMLWorker doesn't read a string directly but instead needs a TextReader (which StringReader subclasses)
                using (var sr = new StringReader(EmailBody))
                {
                    //Parse the HTML
                    htmlWorker.Parse(sr);
                }
            }
            doc.Close();
        }
    }
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Gives me this error:

> Cannot access a closed Stream

How to fix this error?

Comment: If you start [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and then run this code, can you see if the image gets fetched?

Comment: All works good except when there is <img src=""> tag in the Email Body. That means the problem is not in the stream, the problem is in the EmailBody string.

Comment: The name HtmlWorker suggests it has an asynchronous quality. Could it still be running after the stream has been closed?

Comment: The code works if there is no `<img>` tag in the tinymce editor.

Comment: The name `HTMLWorker` suggests that you are using a very old version of iTextSharp, 4.x or older. More recent versions of iTextSharp use `XMLWorker`. Could you try again with iTextSharp 5.5.8?

Comment: ok...i will try with 5.5.8 Version.